# Prove Fibonacci sequence mod 10 is periodic

Tags: proof-explanation, contest-math, pigeonhole-principle

The proof I saw uses the pigeonhole principle.  They list the first $101$ terms beginning with $1,1,2,3,5,...$ and then group them in pairs, $(1,1),(1,2),(2,3),...$, and this gives us $100$ pairs.  Now, since the pair $(0,0)$ can't occur, we must have a pair that repeats, and a pair occurring again, will lead to the same sequence.

**My question**
Why is it that in the $100$ pairs, there are only $100$ possible choices of pairs? and getting rid of $(0,0)$ implies that there are only $99$ left to choose from?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the question says mod 10? It seems from your explanation that maybe it's about mod 100? Update: Sorry, maybe it is mod 10 - I'm just beginning to see why.

Comment: Yes, it's mod $10$

Comment: Apart from the pair $(0,0)$ you can take out all other (even, even) pairs as the sequence also contains odd numbers. And for the same reason exclude all pairs consisting of only $0$ and $5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are taking the Fibonacci sequence modulo $10$, then the only possible values the sequence can take are $0$ through $9$. You cannot pick a number that lies outside of this range, so there are only $100$ choices for pairs. How would you possibly pick something that is not a part of these $100$ pairs?

You are correct in that getting rid of $(0,0)$ implies there are only $99$ pairs left to choose from. This doesn't change the logic of the proof, it only makes sure that we don't end up with a degenerate case.

Comment: Is it a combinations formula you used to get that there are only $100$ choices for pairs?  That's what I'm not seeing.

Comment: You have 10 choices for the first number, and 10 choices for the second number. This gives 10*10 = 100 choices for pairs.

Comment: yup, that was the obvious thing I missed.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I don't really get the point of this question.

Wouldn't Fibonacci Sequence be cyclical for any mod provided we don't hit (0, 0) in which case it stalls?

Comment: Yes, this proof can easily be extended as such, but you would need to understand one case before you can understand the general case. It's perfectly normal for someone to ask about something specific that they don't understand.